# Meaning of last 4 digits in a Samsung RAM memory stick

Tags: memory

I have a Samsung 2GB memory stick installed on my desktop with the following specs: M378B5773CH0-CH9 1042.

My question is what do the last 4 digits stand for?

Answer (score 3):

#### What is the meaning of last 4 digits on a Samsung RAM memory stick?

> M378B5773CH0-CH9 1042.

The last 4 digits `1042` are a code representing the year and week the device was manufactured.

The first part of the number `M378B5773CH0-CH9` is the part number.

> [image]
>
> (5)   Year & Week     Code Manufactured Year & Week code

Source [Label & Code Information](https://web.archive.org/web/20150313005712/http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/support/label-code-info/marking-info/memory-modules/ddr3-dimm)